# FetchType EAGER not working in Windows/MySQL 5.7

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In a Java project that uses Hibernate, I am having difficulties to make a FetchType EAGER work on my development database, which runs under Windows 10 and uses MySQL 5.7 (I also tried MySQL 8).

The strange fact is that when I run the exact same code with the exact same database structure and data (dumped and imported from a machine to another), it does work on a Centos 7/MySQL 5.6 environment.
If I run the code on my Windows machine but connecting to the Centos database, it does work too.
If I run the code on my Centos machine connecting to my Windows database, it does not work.

The version of Hibernate is 5.4.10.

Please find below the code that I use (names of attributes, variables and tables changed, so there might be some mistyping):

Entity:

```
@Entity
@SQLInsert(sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table1(t2_id,t3_id,order) VALUES(?,?,?)")
public class Table1 implements Serializable
    {

    //----------------------------------------------------
    /*
        Attributes / fields definitions :
    */
    public  Table2  t2;
    public  Table3  t3;
    public  Integer order;

    //---------------------------------
    // STATIC FACTORIES
    //---------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------------------
    /**
        Get the list of relations between table2 and table3
    */
    static public ArrayList<Table1> find
        (
        Session     inSession,
        Table3      inTable3
        )
        {
        TypedQuery< Table1 > vQuery = inSession.createQuery( "SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.t3 = :int3", Table1.class );
        vQuery.setParameter( "int3", inTable3 );

        return new ArrayList<>( vQuery.getResultList() );
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"hltp://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="..." default-access="field">
    <class name = "Table1" table = "table1" dynamic-update="true">

        <meta attribute = "class-description">
         ...
        </meta>

        <composite-id>
            <key-many-to-one name="t2" class="Table2"   column="t2" lazy="false"/>
            <key-many-to-one name="t3" class="Table3"   column="t3" lazy="false"/>
        </composite-id>

        <property name = "order" column = "order" not-null="true"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Call of factory:

```
ArrayList< Table1 > vRelations = Table1.find( fDbSession, t3 );
```

On the Centos database, it works like a charm, I get my Table1 elements containing initialized Table2 and Table3 elements.
On the Windows database, all I get is a "HibernateProxy" element.